# Is there a strong named version of Owin.Security.Providers.OpenID

Tags: c#, nuget, owin, openid

We had previously setup an `OpenID` implementation in our web project using `Owin.Security.Providers.OpenID v2.14.0` (installed via `NuGet`).  However, we have recently had a need to turn on self signing on our project.  Since this `dll` is the only `dll` reference in our project which does not have a strong name, we are getting an error whenever we run the site.

There are dozens of `OpenID` options available on `NuGet`.  However, I cannot find a signed version of `Owin.Security.Providers.OpenID`.

This project is hosted on `GitHub`. Is there a way to get a signed/strong named version?

Answer (score 0):

The project developer was kind enough to release a new strongly named version of the dll.  It is, now, accessible on NuGet as version 2.15.1.